# file.html beeing correctly displayed on localhost but not on server

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Im using spingboot for my project. I created some subfolders under "template" and registred those domains as followed on maven.

```
registry.addViewController("/websitefolder/mywebsite").setViewName("mywebsite");
```

i also tried it like this:

```
registry.addViewController("/websitefolder/mywebsite").setViewName("websitefolder/mywebsite");
```

The Problem is that on localhost:8080 the webpage is beeing displayed correctly but on the testserver i get a "505" error.
localhost url:

```
localhost8080/websitefolder/mywebsite
```

server url:

```
ip.ip.ip.ip/server-test/websitefolder/mywebsite
```

Does anyone know if the registry on maven is wrong or if i should do it differently?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is server-test a path? If so you need to change the registry:

```
registry.addViewController("/server-test/websitefolder/mywebsite").setViewName("websitefolder/mywebsite");
```

Answer (score 0):

simply change the registry for the server-test path

```
registry.addViewController
("/server-test/websitefolder/mywebsite").setViewName("websitefolder/mywebsite");
```